# Как вытянуть данные из списка python?

Tags: python

Здраствуйте, пишу бота для Skype за основу взял библиотеку SkPy, но столкнулся с проблемой. Функция `getMsgs` возвращает такие данные

```
[SkypeTextMsg(id=u'1549300682719', type=u'RichText', time=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 4, 17, 18, 2, 703000), clientId=u'16593484836808786853', userId=u'live:m_tech_4', chatId=u'19:42bd94aef87c496c88067ae137c4b998@thread.skype', content=u'ds')
```

как мне можно вытянуть, скажем вот ету часть `time=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 4, 17, 18, 2, 703000)` что бы числа остались int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим список с сообщениями называется `messages`. Тогда для получения времени первого сообщения попробуйте сделать:

```
msg_time = messages[0].time
print(msg_time)
```